# Java mget is much slower than http mget when in high concurrency environment

Tags: elasticsearch

when i test the performance of mget method with HP Loadrunning, i found that java's mget method is much slower than http's mget method, java's mget method is almost 5 times slower than http's mget method.

here is my test method.

```
MultiGetResponse multiGetResponse = client.prepareMultiGet().add(index, type, ids).execute().actionGet();


curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_mget' -d '{ "ids" : ["1", "2", "3", ...] }'
```

But the weird thing is that i send a single request respectively, their average time spent is the same.